# Adicionar opacidade entre menu e o fundo

Tags: css, html5

Tenho um header lateral e quando ele é exibido preciso que o plano atrás dela tenha uma opacidade, já tentei várias maneiras que encontrei na internet, mas nenhuma deu certo se algum puder me ajudar ficarei grata segue o css e uma imagem.

Imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
.header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #efefef, #ffffff);
    box-shadow: -0.8px 0.6px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    height: 70px;
    width: 100% !important;
    mix-blend-mode: undefined;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #efefef, #ffffff);
    box-shadow: -0.8px 0.6px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.71;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #666666 !important;
    li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul {
        padding-left: 60px;
    }
    .nav>li.active a,
    .nav>li>a:active {
        border-bottom: solid #66bbb0;
        border-width: 4px;
        color: #66bbb0 !important;
        background-color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    li {
        line-height: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        a {
            padding: 0 10px;
            line-height: 70px;
            height: 70px;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #666666;
        }
    }
    .left {
        float: left;
    }
    .right {
        float: right;
    }
    .nav>li>a:hover {
        text-decoration: none !important;
        background-color: #e6e6e6 !important;
        color: #666666 !important;
    }
    #language {
        width: 80px;
        ul {
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 80px;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            img {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
    }   

    @media screen and (max-width: 650px){

        .navbar-toggle{
            z-index: 999;            
        }
        .collapse{
            top: 0;
            right:-100%;
            display: block !important;
        }
        .in.collapse{
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .lateral {
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 87%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;         
            background-color: #fff;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            -webkit-transition: all .5s linear; 
               -moz-transition: all .5s linear; 
                 -ms-transition:all .5s linear; 
                 -o-transition: all .5s linear;   
                    transition: all .5s linear;      
        } 


    }    
}
```

Comment: Ana aproveite e coloque o HTML, só com CSS fica complicado ter certeza se a resposta vai funcionar pra vc ou não

Comment: Eu não consigo porque é muito grande.Eu colo e não vai o código todo.

Comment: Ana coloque só a parte do HTML envolvido na questão, pelo menos um exemplo simples que de para gente simular o seu problema e te dar uma reposta precisa.

Comment: Sem todo o seu código fica difícil dizer. Porque não da para saber se o seu header está ocupando width: 100% da página ou com base em um elemento pai. Se ele estiver ocupando width: 100% da página. Basta adicionar um background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); na sua classe header. caso ele não esteja preenchendo 100% da página, primeiro tem q verificar se algum elemento pai esta, e se estiver, adicionar o background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); nele. Caso contrário vc vai precisar criar uma dive que preencha toda a pagina e usar z-index para posicioná-la atrás do seu header.

Comment: Ana, mande via https://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, você está fazendo um menu dropdown e está querendo colocar uma opacidade fora do menu, quando abre o mesmo. Correto?

Se for isto, pode-se usar o `.active`, adicione assim no seu arquivo `.css`:

```css
header.active {
    box-shadow: [ . . . ] rgba(cor,cor,cor, opacidade);
}
```

Usando o `.active` você irá ativar o `box-shadow` apenas depois do menu está ativo/aberto!